# how to install apache cassandra in bluemix cloud?

Tags: cassandra, ibm-cloud

I have IBM bluemix account , can some one provide me pointers on how to install apache cassandra in ibm bluemix ? Or is there any other free or limited trial cloud where i can install cassandra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apache Cassandra is not natively supported on Bluemix, your only option will be to create a docker container with Cassandra installed on it and upload to [Bluemix's container service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html). This will be the only way to create a DB not available on the platform.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Rondeau for your comment. I will try cassandra with docker. Additionally I also want to try out the following 1. Docker nodes with a tomcat engine , which can be managed by mesos. Is this option available in bluemix ?